# Scrapy async item pipeline

Tags: scrapy, twisted

I'm writing an item pipeline that drops items onto a RabbitMQ queue using Pika. At the moment I'm using a blocking/synchronous approach which is obviously not a great idea. I would like to use an async approach similar to [this](http://pika.readthedocs.org/en/latest/examples/twisted_example.html) but I can't work out how to add a deferred task to the already running reactor. For example the sample code for the twisted version of the pika connection shows this:

```
d = cc.connectTCP('hostname', 5672)
d.addCallback(lambda protocol: protocol.ready)
d.addCallback(run)
reactor.run() # Problem is, it's already running
```

Does anyone have any pointers for how to add deferred tasks to a reactor that is already started?

Comment: What happens if you just removes the `reactor.run()` part, my intuition says that it would just work because a running reaction is already in place, have you tried?

Comment: @brunsgaard yeah I tried but nothing happens. I'm going to read through the source code for scrapy to see if I can find any clues. I have a feeling that I need to return the deferred (d) somehow

Comment: I do not follow.. If i was you I would start with something simple like this https://gist.github.com/brunsgaard/b11ca0b2023f66f2fea5 in the pipeline, just to be sure that the reactor is running and the deferred is fired. (code is taken from the twisted tutorial on deferreds)

Comment: To me it seems like it just works, other people are doing it. https://github.com/darkrho/dirbot-mysql/blob/19b750f88279c0bbd50ccfa39709d57628057ac9/dirbot/pipelines.py#L58-L67

Comment: I followed your gist and it worked but only when I added a 'return d' statement at the end of the open_spider method. See https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e04807c5352c27053f38 ... does this make sense to you?

Comment: @Tobi, I just had a breif look at the scrapy code, to me it seems like pipelining are done in parrallel http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#concurrent-items, I guess that by returning a deferred the the deferred is thrown into the reactor in the main thread.. does that make sense?

Comment: me and you are both stupid, maybe we should read the documentation.. :) http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/signals.html#spider-opened and http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/signals.html#deferred-signal-handlers

Comment: I think is is handeled, right here 
https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/e748ca50ca3e83ac703e02538a27236fedd53a7d/scrapy/utils/signal.py#L52-L53

Comment: Yes it makes sense now, I didn't realise that pipelining is done in parallel and it would explain why the code wasn't running. I really appreciate you taking the time to read through the docs and make sense of it all. I did take a look myself but I was a bit overwhelmed being new to Python (I'm a die hard Java man!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you can use any Twisted API after the reactor has been started (with some notable exceptions, for example `reactor.run` ;).  Twisted APIs that initiate some asynchronous operation are happy to do so against a reactor that is running (as opposed to one that hasn't been started yet).  They are also mostly happy to do so against a reactor that hasn't yet been started (though little or no progress will be made until the reactor is started).

If you have some code running in the same thread as a reactor is running, you can just use Twisted APIs (such as `ClientCreator.connectTCP` as your example appears to use; separately, though, take a look at the new "endpoint" APIs, they're basically better than `ClientCreator` in every way) and they will work fine.

If they're not working fine, the problem may be that they don't do what you expect them to do, they're reporting an error that you're ignoring (as the example in the question seems to do), or the code isn't actually running in the same thread as the reactor.

Comment: Jean-Paul, Your last point about the threads proved to be correct as brunsgaard points out in the comments to my question. Thanks to both of you for your help